# HQL Select Query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, dao

How to select a row based on a unique column.
In my table, Id is auto generated.  I am using phone number to select the row which is unique in my table schema.

Ex:

```
 Id    Phone      Name
 1     2209897    abc
 2     5436567    def
```

Here, Id is primary key.
Phone is unique.

I am using phone to login.
I donot want a list to be generated but a single row as output.

```
 @Repository
 public class CustomerDetailsDAOImpl implements CustomerDetailsDAO {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional
public List<CustomerDetails> getCustomer(String customerPhone) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Query q = session.createQuery("from CustomerDetails where customerPhone =:p");
    q.setParameter("p", customerPhone);

    List<CustomerDetails> customer = q.getResultList();
    session.close();
    return customer;

}
```

Comment: Don't use `List`, just use `CustomerDetails customer = q.getResultList();`, if `:p` returns more than 1 row then you will get a `ResultSizeException`, but if all the phone numbers in the database are certainly unique then you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: @px06 Possibly you were intending to advise to use a method other than q.getResultList() there.

Comment: @Gimby Sorry, you're right. It should be: `List<CustomerDetails> getList = q.getResultList(); Customer customer = getList.get(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getSingleResult() instead of using getListResult().This Executes a SELECT query that returns a single untyped result. So whenever you expect a single record to be retrieved with unique type, should use getSingleResult().

```
 @Repository
 public class CustomerDetailsDAOImpl implements CustomerDetailsDAO {

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional
public List<CustomerDetails> getCustomer(String customerPhone) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Query q = session.createQuery("from CustomerDetails where customerPhone =:p");
    q.setParameter("p", customerPhone);

    CustomerDetails customer = q.getSingleResult();
    session.close();
    return customer;

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `q.getResultList()` instead use `q.getSingleResult()` as phone number is unique in your database, the query will return single object of `CustomerDetails` class.

```
public CustomerDetails getCustomer(String customerPhone) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Query q = session.createQuery("from CustomerDetails where customerPhone =:p");
    CustomerDetails customer=null;
    q.setParameter("p", customerPhone);
    try{
        customer = q.getResultList();
    }catch(NoResultException ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }finally{
        session.close();
    }

    return customer;

}
```

**Note** : If your query does not retrieve any data from database then `getSingleResult()` will throw `NoResultException` exception.
So you have to handle this exception from your side.

You can use above example for your reference. I have added code for `NoResultException` exception handling.

Comment: [Why you should never use getSingleResult() in JPA](http://sysout.be/2011/03/09/why-you-should-never-use-getsingleresult-in-jpa/), worth looking at.

Comment: I agree with you @px06. But user3550981 want to return single result so I proposed this solution.